# Problema com switch dentro do laço While

Tags: c, while, switch

Gostaria de uma ajuda para solucionar o problema que estou tendo com o switch dentro do laço, ele não finalza nunca, fica num loop eterno. O que devo fazer para solucionar ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
char nome[50], passatempo2, passatempo4, musica2, musica4, filme2, filme4, vicio2, vicio4;
int op, sexo, idade, idade2, idade3, idade4, passatempo, passatempo3, musica, musica3, filme, filme3, auto_declara, auto_declara2, vicio, vicio3;
int ab, valor_aluguel, quartos, banheiros, proximidade, adicional, ba, valor_aluguel2, quartos2, banheiros2, proximidade2, adicional2, profissao, profissao2;

printf("Ola, seja bem-vindo ao Colega de Quarto, como voce se chama ? ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]s", &nome);
printf("\n");
printf("O que voce deseja, %s ?\n\n", nome);
printf("1 - Anunciar\n\n");
printf("2 - Procurar\n\n");
scanf("%d", &op);

while(op==1)
{
    printf("\n");

    printf("O que voce vai preencher primeiro %s ?\n\n", nome);
    printf("1 - Perfil\n\n");
    printf("2 - Caracteristicas da residencia\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &ba);
    switch(ba)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("\nFormule seu perfil de acordo com as opcoes abaixo: \n");

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Sexo---\n");
        printf("1 - Masculino\n");
        printf("2 - Feminino\n");
        scanf("%d", &sexo);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Idade---\n");
        printf("1 - 16 a 19 anos\n");
        printf("2 - 20 a 21 anos\n");
        printf("3 - outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &idade3);
        if (idade3 == 3)
        {
            printf("Quantos anos voce tem ?\n");
            scanf("%d", &idade4);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Profissao---\n");
        printf("1 - Estudante\n");
        printf("2 - Profissional\n");
        printf("3 - Aposentado\n");
        scanf("%d", &profissao);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Hobby---\n");
        printf("1 - Ler\n");
        printf("2 - Praticar esportes\n");
        printf("3 - Festar\n");
        printf("4 - Outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &passatempo3);
        if (passatempo3 == 4)
        {
            printf("Qual ?\n");
            scanf("%s", &passatempo3);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Gosto Musical---\n");
        printf("1 - Rock\n");
        printf("2 - Funk\n");
        printf("3 - Sertanejo\n");
        printf("4 - Outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &musica3);
        if (musica3 == 4)
        {
            printf("Qual ?\n");
            scanf("%s", &musica4);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Tipo de Filme---\n");
        printf("1 - Acao\n");
        printf("2 - Suspense\n");
        printf("3 - Terror\n");;
        printf("4 - Comedia\n");
        printf("5 - Outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &filme3);
        if (filme3 == 5)
        {
            printf("Qual ?\n");
            scanf("%s", &filme4);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Voce e---\n");
        printf("1 - Caseira(o)\n");
        printf("2 - Festeira(o)\n");
        printf("3 - Um pouco dos dois\n");
        scanf("%d", &auto_declara2);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Voce faz uso de---\n");
        printf("1 - Alcool\n");
        printf("2 - Cigarro\n");
        printf("3 - Entorpecentes\n");
        printf("4 - Nenhum\n");
        printf("5 - Outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &vicio3);
        if (vicio3 == 5)
        {
            printf("Qual \n");
            scanf("%s", &vicio4);
        }

        break;
        system("cls");

    case 2:
        printf("\n");

        printf("---Valor do aluguel---\n");
        printf("1 - R$ 250 - R$ 300\n");
        printf("2 - R$ 300 - R$ 350\n");
        printf("3 - R$ 350 - R$ 400\n");
        scanf("%d", &valor_aluguel2);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Quantidade de quartos na casa---\n");
        printf("1 - 1 Quarto\n");
        printf("2 - 2 Quartos\n");
        printf("3 - 3 Quartos\n");
        scanf("%d", &quartos2);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Quantidade de banheiros na casa---\n");
        printf("1 - 1 Banheiro\n");
        printf("2 - 2 Banheiros\n");
        printf("3 - 3 Banheiros\n");
        scanf("%d", &banheiros2);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Proximo de----\n");
        printf("1 - Banco, farmacia, ponto de onibus, supermecado\n");
        printf("2 - Banco, ponto de onibus, supermecado\n");
        printf("3 - Farmacia, ponto de onibus, supermecado\n");
        scanf("%d", &proximidade2);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Adicional---\n");
        printf("1 - Garagem\n");
        printf("2 - Quintal\n");
        printf("3 - Piscina\n");
        printf("4 - Nenhum\n");
        scanf("%d", &adicional2);

        break;
        system("cls");
    }
}

while(op==2)
{
    printf("\n");

    printf("O que voce vai preencher primeiro %s ?\n\n", nome);
    printf("1 - Perfil\n\n");
    printf("2 - Caracteristicas da residencia\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &ab);
    switch(ab)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("\nFormule seu perfil de acordo com as opcoes abaixo: \n");

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Sexo---\n");
        printf("1 - Masculino\n");
        printf("2 - Feminino\n");
        scanf("%d", &sexo);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Idade---\n");
        printf("1 - 16 a 19 anos\n");
        printf("2 - 20 a 21 anos\n");
        printf("3 - outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &idade);
        if (idade == 3)
        {
            printf("Quantos anos voce tem ?\n");
            scanf("%d", &idade2);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Profissao---\n");
        printf("1 - Estudante\n");
        printf("2 - Profissional\n");
        printf("3 - Aposentado\n");
        scanf("%d", &profissao2);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Hobby---\n");
        printf("1 - Ler\n");
        printf("2 - Praticar esportes\n");
        printf("3 - Festar\n");
        printf("4 - Outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &passatempo);
        if (passatempo == 4)
        {
            printf("Qual ?\n");
            scanf("%s", &passatempo2);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Gosto Musical---\n");
        printf("1 - Rock\n");
        printf("2 - Funk\n");
        printf("3 - Sertanejo\n");
        printf("4 - Outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &musica);
        if (musica == 4)
        {
            printf("Qual ?\n");
            scanf("%s", &musica2);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Tipo de Filme---\n");
        printf("1 - Acao\n");
        printf("2 - Suspense\n");
        printf("3 - Terror\n");;
        printf("4 - Comedia\n");
        printf("5 - Outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &filme);
        if (filme == 5)
        {
            printf("Qual ?\n");
            scanf("%s", &filme2);
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Voce e---\n");
        printf("1 - Caseira(o)\n");
        printf("2 - Festeira(o)\n");
        printf("3 - Um pouco dos dois\n");
        scanf("%d", &auto_declara);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Voce faz uso de---\n");
        printf("1 - Alcool\n");
        printf("2 - Cigarro\n");
        printf("3 - Entorpecentes\n");
        printf("4 - Nenhum\n");
        printf("5 - Outro\n");
        scanf("%d", &vicio);
        if (vicio == 5)
        {
            printf("Qual \n");
            scanf("%s", &vicio2);
        }

        break;
        system("cls");

    case 2:
        printf("\n");

        printf("---Valor do aluguel---\n");
        printf("1 - R$ 250 - R$ 300\n");
        printf("2 - R$ 300 - R$ 350\n");
        printf("3 - R$ 350 - R$ 400\n");
        scanf("%d", &valor_aluguel);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Quantidade de quartos na casa---\n");
        printf("1 - 1 Quarto\n");
        printf("2 - 2 Quartos\n");
        printf("3 - 3 Quartos\n");
        scanf("%d", &quartos);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Quantidade de banheiros na casa---\n");
        printf("1 - 1 Banheiro\n");
        printf("2 - 2 Banheiros\n");
        printf("3 - 3 Banheiros\n");
        scanf("%d", &banheiros);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Proximo de----\n");
        printf("1 - Banco, farmacia, ponto de onibus, supermecado\n");
        printf("2 - Banco, ponto de onibus, supermecado\n");
        printf("3 - Farmacia, ponto de onibus, supermecado\n");
        scanf("%d", &proximidade);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Adicional---\n");
        printf("1 - Garagem\n");
        printf("2 - Quintal\n");
        printf("3 - Piscina\n");
        printf("4 - Nenhum\n");
        scanf("%d", &adicional);

        break;
        system("cls");

    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: No Console mostra o tipo do erro em qual linha?

Comment: O código é extramente desorganizado e confuso, e por isso é bem difícil entendê-lo, o que ocasiona erros nem sempre fáceis de achar. Se fizsse cada tarefa em uma função, não declarasse um monte de variáveis no começo da função o erro talvez nem aconteceria, mas se ainda tivesse acontecido seria fácil localizá-lo, então minha sugestão é repensar a forma de codificar isso, até pra aprender fazer do jeito certo. O problema é que a variável `op` que controla a saída do *loop* nunca é alterada dentro dele, então não sai. Nem sei porque existe tal variável. Pensando bem nem deveria ser um laço aí.

Comment: Eu não quero dar uma resposta porque pra arrumar isso de verdade dará muito trabalho, para arrumar mais ou menos eu prefiro não responder porque isso desensina, mas a dica está dada, o laço deveria ser mais externo englobando praticamente toda função e onde tem `while` deveria ser outro `switch`. Mas reforço, será mais fácil se quebrar cada parte em uma função diferente.

Answer (score 1):

while(op==1), essa condição aqui vai ser verdadeira sempre e ocasionar o loop infinito se voce digitar 1 para o valor de op e não alterar ele depois ou dar um break para sair do laço.